# Creating sqlite tables that will save between sessions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, persistence

Is it possible to dynamically create sqlite tables in objective c that will save between iPhone sessions?  If so, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly you want to save? You can always serialise objects if you want and then deserialize it.

Comment: i want to save rows from the original sqlite file that the user selected to add to a list.  I want the user to be able to have many different lists that they select on their own this way.